# Problem with toLocaleDateString and Date.Prototype using MailMerge in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm Attempting to create a Merge between some sheet Data, a doc template and a final doc template.

Mainly, I have access to these files like this:

```
  var contratotemplate = DocumentApp.openById(contratotemplateId);
  var contratonovo = DocumentApp.openById(contratonovoId);
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(planilhaId).getSheetByName("Contratos Ref Marca");
```

Than, used this code to pick each Data from a Range that I want.

`var data =  ws.getRange(3,1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

The Problem is here when I try to replacetext with cell information from my sheet trough another function callback (the one that actually replace text with info):

```
data.forEach(function(r){
      CriarMailMerge(
        r[30].getDate()+"/"+r[30].getMonth()+"/"+r[30].getFullYear(),
        paragrafosTemplate,
        contratonovo);
  });
```

The result is this:

`11/5/2019 //in contratonovoId field supposed to have the correct date.`

I've already tried .toLocaleDateString()

The result is:

`June, 11 2019.`

Which solves my problem, but I can't find a way to bring that info into Brazilian Portuguese.

Can u guys help me?

Comment: I Used this and worked:

```r[30].getDate()+"/"+("0" + (r[30].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"/"+r[30].getFullYear(),```

Comment: I would recommend posting this as an answer to your question and accepting it so that people know you have found a solution

Comment: Done it! Ty, Passer-By!

Answer (score 1):

I Used this and worked: 
`r[30].getDate()+"/"+("0" + (r[30].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"/"+r[30].getFullYear(),`

RESULT

`11/06/2019`